# Why can't we shift an integer number more than the size of integer?

Tags: java, data-structures, bit-shift

In a thread related to 'Bitwise Operators' on GFG, it was written that,

> If the number is shifted more than the size of an integer, the
> behaviour is undefined. For example, 1 << 33 is undefined if integers
> are stored using 32 bits

But when I tried to perform the same operations in Java, I'm getting the below results,

1<<32 => 1

1<<33 => 2

1<<34 => 4

1<<35 => 8

And these results are justified also. As an integer is of 32 bits, so when I left shift 1 by 32 bits, it travels through all the 31 bits and comes back to the 0th position, hence we get the value 1. And the same goes for <<33, <<34, and <<35 also I believe.

Then how the results are undefined? Is it not undefined for Java?

This is the link to the thread: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/

Comment: "Undefined result" means that you have no guarantee what will happen in this case. On different computers, different virtual machines, different versions of virtual machines you can get different results. For example, in your environment you got 1<<32 => 1. But in another environment it can be, for example, 0 (all bits are moved out, so shift to any number larger than 31 will be zero), etc.

Comment: In C and C++ the behaviour is undefined, as described in GFG. In Java (which is a completely different language) the bevaviour is well defined and described in [JLS - Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19). Namely, for `int` values Java uses only the lowest 5 bits, for `long` values only the lowest 6 bits, which reduces the shift count to values from 0 to 31 for int and 0 to 63 for long.

Comment: "As an Integer is of 32 bits, so when I left shift 1 by 32 bits, it travels through all the 31 bits and comes back to the 0th position, hence we get the value 1.": no, that would be a rotation operation. That left shifting is not a rotation operation can easily be shown by `System.out.println(2 << 31);` which prints 0, whereas a rotation operation would print out 1.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, when you're shifting an `int`, only the lower 5 bits of the shift operand are considered.  So the behavior is defined, but its not want you want it to be.

This is spelled out here in the language specification https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19 and also in the definitions of the virtual machine instructions for the shifts, like *ishl* here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ishl

As for why... it's because that's what the x86 (and I expect many other) CPU's shift instructions do, and the java language designers didn't want to add overhead to calculate it another way.

Because they actually defined it, if you run java on an architecture that doesn't have this problem, it will explicitly mask out the higher bits in the shift.  C and C++ compilers leave the behavior undefined so their compilers will never have to do that.